# asp.net core 2.0 authorize with a specific scheme

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, jwt

I have an app with a cookie and jwt auth schemes. This is the `ConfigureServices` code:

```cs
var authTokenSettings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(TokenProviderSettings)).Get<TokenProviderSettings>();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(authSection.AuthenticationScheme, u =>
{
    u.Cookie.Name = authSection.AuthCookieName;
    u.LoginPath = new PathString(authSection.LoginPath);
    u.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Index";
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = authTokenSettings.Issuer,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = authTokenSettings.Audience,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authTokenSettings.Key)),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    };
});
```

Now I need to use cookie scheme on one method and jwt on other. I've added appropriate attributes

```cs
([Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)])
```

But these attributes are ignored, and the default scheme is used. If I do not specify default scheme, I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was
>   specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

What's wrong with code?

Comment: What do you mean the attributes are ignored? You specify Jwt as the scheme in the Authorize attribute, which is *also* the default according to your config. So of course you get the “default” scheme. – And you cannot use cookie authentication on its own, as it cannot challenge on its own. It will pass challenge requests to the default challenge scheme, so with your config, you would keep running the Jwt authentication.

Comment: I have app with cookie authentication, and add jwt one for 2 methods. If I set cookie authentication scheme as default - jwt auth is ignored

Comment: Are you sure it is ignored? Or is it just that it is run after your default?

Comment: according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?tabs=aspnetcore2x it should work

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. Attribute `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` defines authentication scheme only if added to controller, not to action

Comment: I don't think that's true. I think you may need to have the `[Authorize]` attribute on each action in a 'mixed' controller rather than having one at controller level and trying to 'override' on specific actions.

Comment: I've tryed it, but faced the problem, described above. And when I splitted my controller into 2 different and added the attributes to each - it worked

Answer (score 0):

No need for separate controllers, you can implement IControllerModelConvention

```cs
public class AddAuthorizeFiltersControllerConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        if (controller.ControllerName.Contains("Api"))
        {
            controller.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("apipolicy"));
        }
        else
        {
            controller.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("defaultpolicy"));
        }
    }
}
```

Or implement IActionModelConvention

```cs
public class AddAuthorizeFiltersActionConvention : IActionModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        if (action.ActionName.Contains("GetUser"))
        {
            action.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("apipolicy"));
        }
        else
        {
            action.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("defaultpolicy"));
        }
    }
}
```

Reference and credit https://joonasw.net/view/apply-authz-by-default

Comment: There is an error in your code. If you filter for certain actions but use "action.Controller.Filters" it will apply it to the regarding controller and hence, to all actions within this controller. Use "action.Filters" instead.